# Reason for Redis `dir` path changing dynamically

Tags: redis, server, servicestack.redis

We are facing an issue with redis, where the `'dir'` path for the redis is getting set without any notice.

Resulting in the following error (while writing to redis).

> MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently
>   not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are
>   disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error.

**Information** we have to support this.

**- Redis Config file**

A look at our `redis.conf` (located at `/etc/redis/redis.conf`) hint us that the `dir` path value is...

```
# The working directory.
#
# The DB will be written inside this directory, with the filename specified
# above using the 'dbfilename' configuration directive.
#
# The Append Only File will also be created inside this directory.
#
# Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name.
dir /var/lib/redis
```

**- Redis INFO Result.**

> {"redis_version"=>"2.8.17", "redis_git_sha1"=>"00000000",
>   "redis_git_dirty"=>"0", "redis_build_id"=>"e2de0295da7f0ee1",
>   "redis_mode"=>"standalone", "os"=>"Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64",
>   "arch_bits"=>"64", "multiplexing_api"=>"epoll",
>   "gcc_version"=>"4.9.2", "process_id"=>"6860",
>   "run_id"=>"4ecd0ff19798a88793e7a3ce281f398ba9aa2f5a",
>   "tcp_port"=>"6379", "uptime_in_seconds"=>"99525",
>   "uptime_in_days"=>"1", "hz"=>"10", "lru_clock"=>"11741717",
>   "config_file"=>"/etc/redis/redis.conf", "connected_clients"=>"2",
>   "client_longest_output_list"=>"0", "client_biggest_input_buf"=>"0",
>   "blocked_clients"=>"0", "used_memory"=>"784840",
>   "used_memory_human"=>"766.45K", "used_memory_rss"=>"3624960",
>   "used_memory_peak"=>"784840", "used_memory_peak_human"=>"766.45K",
>   "used_memory_lua"=>"33792", "mem_fragmentation_ratio"=>"4.62",
>   "mem_allocator"=>"jemalloc-3.6.0", "loading"=>"0",
>   "rdb_changes_since_last_save"=>"0", "rdb_bgsave_in_progress"=>"0",
>   "rdb_last_save_time"=>"1454582288", "rdb_last_bgsave_status"=>"ok",
>   "rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec"=>"0", "rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec"=>"-1",
>   "aof_enabled"=>"0", "aof_rewrite_in_progress"=>"0",
>   "aof_rewrite_scheduled"=>"0", "aof_last_rewrite_time_sec"=>"-1",
>   "aof_current_rewrite_time_sec"=>"-1",
>   "aof_last_bgrewrite_status"=>"ok", "aof_last_write_status"=>"ok",
>   "total_connections_received"=>"12",
>   "total_commands_processed"=>"4651", "instantaneous_ops_per_sec"=>"0",
>   "rejected_connections"=>"0", "sync_full"=>"0", "sync_partial_ok"=>"0",
>   "sync_partial_err"=>"0", "expired_keys"=>"0", "evicted_keys"=>"0",
>   "keyspace_hits"=>"0", "keyspace_misses"=>"0", "pubsub_channels"=>"0",
>   "pubsub_patterns"=>"0", "latest_fork_usec"=>"206", "role"=>"master",
>   "connected_slaves"=>"0", "master_repl_offset"=>"0",
>   "repl_backlog_active"=>"0", "repl_backlog_size"=>"1048576",
>   "repl_backlog_first_byte_offset"=>"0", "repl_backlog_histlen"=>"0",
>   "used_cpu_sys"=>"57.78", "used_cpu_user"=>"25.71",
>   "used_cpu_sys_children"=>"0.00", "used_cpu_user_children"=>"0.00",
>   "db0"=>"keys=2851,expires=0,avg_ttl=0"}

Key point

```
 redis.info['config_file'] 

 => /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Process id of Redis

```
 redis.info['process_id']

 => 6860
```

**- Redis Config**

And then I inspected redis config and...

```
redis.config "get" ,"dir"

=> ["dir", "/etc/ssh"]
## ideally should be /var/lib/redis
```

Things, I did to fix the above error.

```
redis.config "set" ,"dir","/var/lib/redis"
=> "OK" 

redis.config "get", "dir"
=> ["dir", "/var/lib/redis"]
```

This sort of fix it (the above issue). But for *temporary* purpose only because.....

**After couple of hours** I noticed this.

```
redis.config "get" ,"dir"
=> ["dir", "/etc/ssh"]
```

Inspecting the redis config again

**- Redis Info**

> {"redis_version"=>"2.8.17", "redis_git_sha1"=>"00000000",
>   "redis_git_dirty"=>"0", "redis_build_id"=>"e2de0295da7f0ee1",
>   "redis_mode"=>"standalone", "os"=>"Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64",
>   "arch_bits"=>"64", "multiplexing_api"=>"epoll",
>   "gcc_version"=>"4.9.2", "process_id"=>"6860",
>   "run_id"=>"4ecd0ff19798a88793e7a3ce281f398ba9aa2f5a",
>   "tcp_port"=>"6379", "uptime_in_seconds"=>"109032",
>   "uptime_in_days"=>"1", "hz"=>"10", "lru_clock"=>"11751224",
>   "config_file"=>"/etc/redis/redis.conf", "connected_clients"=>"2",
>   "client_longest_output_list"=>"0", "client_biggest_input_buf"=>"0",
>   "blocked_clients"=>"0", "used_memory"=>"788984",
>   "used_memory_human"=>"770.49K", "used_memory_rss"=>"3629056",
>   "used_memory_peak"=>"808952", "used_memory_peak_human"=>"789.99K",
>   "used_memory_lua"=>"33792", "mem_fragmentation_ratio"=>"4.60",
>   "mem_allocator"=>"jemalloc-3.6.0", "loading"=>"0",
>   "rdb_changes_since_last_save"=>"82", "rdb_bgsave_in_progress"=>"0",
>   "rdb_last_save_time"=>"1454591521", "rdb_last_bgsave_status"=>"ok",
>   "rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec"=>"0", "rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec"=>"-1",
>   "aof_enabled"=>"0", "aof_rewrite_in_progress"=>"0",
>   "aof_rewrite_scheduled"=>"0", "aof_last_rewrite_time_sec"=>"-1",
>   "aof_current_rewrite_time_sec"=>"-1",
>   "aof_last_bgrewrite_status"=>"ok", "aof_last_write_status"=>"ok",
>   "total_connections_received"=>"14",
>   "total_commands_processed"=>"6966", "instantaneous_ops_per_sec"=>"0",
>   "rejected_connections"=>"0", "sync_full"=>"0", "sync_partial_ok"=>"0",
>   "sync_partial_err"=>"0", "expired_keys"=>"0", "evicted_keys"=>"0",
>   "keyspace_hits"=>"0", "keyspace_misses"=>"0", "pubsub_channels"=>"0",
>   "pubsub_patterns"=>"0", "latest_fork_usec"=>"135", "role"=>"master",
>   "connected_slaves"=>"0", "master_repl_offset"=>"0",
>   "repl_backlog_active"=>"0", "repl_backlog_size"=>"1048576",
>   "repl_backlog_first_byte_offset"=>"0", "repl_backlog_histlen"=>"0",
>   "used_cpu_sys"=>"62.96", "used_cpu_user"=>"27.97",
>   "used_cpu_sys_children"=>"0.00", "used_cpu_user_children"=>"0.00",
>   "db0"=>"keys=2902,expires=0,avg_ttl=0"}

Key point.

```
 redis.info["process_id"]
 => 6860

 redis.info['config_file']
 => /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

So,

1. Redis Server was never restarted. (`process_id` says a lot about this).
2. Redis is picking the correct config file i.e. `/etc/redis/redis.conf`.

### Question.

So, If point 1, and 2 are true what is causing `redis` to set the `config` `dir` value to `/etc/ssh` after some hours? ( **I have reset the config 5-6 times since yesterday.**)

**Note:**

Also restarted the server (**yesterday**) in a hope that the issue would be resolved permanently. But with no luck.

**Note:**

Responding to @Keith answer

Yes! the server is perfectly behind a *restrictive* firewall.

Thought?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently saw an attack that utilized this as a strategy.  Is your server behind a restrictive firewall?

REF: http://antirez.com/news/96

Comment: updated the question and believe me as I say the server is as secure as it can be behind secure firewall. Appreciate you answer then. Thanks

Comment: The facts say otherwise. Your Redis instance is being repeatedly compromised. This is indisputable.

Comment: Link only answers should be accompanied by text describing the solution in the event the link goes away